# SQL Question: Return the number of email sends for each campaign sent in January 2020

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I'm trying to answer the below question using SQL. Can you help? Thank you!

**Question**: return the number of email sends for each campaign sent in January 2020.

Use the following information:

- Table name: `email_events`
- Columns: `username, date, event, campaign`

Example row:

```
Emily, 2020-01-01, sent, dyson_vacuum
```

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(campaign) WHERE date=2020-01-01 FROM email_events
```

[This website has full of great examples if you ever need to check yourself.](https://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/count)

Comment: Thank you! But the question is a bit more complex. It asks me for the number of emails sends in each campaign, not the not number of campaigns.

Comment: Oh crap, yeah. That'll teach me to go StackOverflow when I'm exhausted. The answer above seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple filtering on the date column, and aggregation on the campaign:

```
select campaign, count(*)
from email_events
where date >= DATE '2020-01-01' and date < DATE '2019-01-01' and event = 'sent'
group by campaign
order by campaign
```

The actual syntax for date litterals may vary across databases. The above uses standard ANSI SQL, which may, or may not be supported in the RDBMS that you are using (but it sure has an equivalent).

Comment: Thank you for this! Since the question is asking me to count the number of emails within a campaign... doesn't the select statement have to count the number emails that have been sent? Am wondering if this is correct: select count (event)... where event = send... and then add the campaign piece?

Comment: @Logan: mm yes, you need the filtering on the `'sent'` event. I upated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you. i am clearly a beginner and still learning. does the count(*) in the select statement count the number of emails, too?

Comment: @Logan: it counts the number of rows in the group (ie having the same `campaign`). So yes, this gives you the number of emails for the campaign.

Comment: Welcome @Logan. If my answer properly responded to your question, then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by clicking the check sign... Thanks.